# Edit mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, prepend

I want to edit an entire mysql table's row.

I don't really know mysql at all, so in basic programming this is what I want to do:

from row year in table videos:

The key here is that I want to **prepend** 19/20 and not add it.

```
if (year < 50)
    year = year+2000
else
    year = year+1900
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Just add `1900` or `2000` instead of prepending `"19"` or `"20"`?

Comment: I think you mean `year >= 50`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET year = year + IF(year >= 50, 1900, 2000)
```

This will work both if your column is an integer type and also if it is a character type.

Comment: I tried this, but I think it's backwards.  I was getting 2089 and 1911 (ex).

Comment: @Switz: I think it's your question that is backwards. ;-) Now I've updated  to answer what you *thought* you asked instead of what you *actually* asked. You should change your question too.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> create table years (year int);

// populate
mysql> INSERT INTO years VALUES (50);
mysql> INSERT INTO years VALUES (90);
mysql> INSERT INTO years VALUES (40);
mysql> INSERT INTO years VALUES (85);

// update
mysql> UPDATE years SET year = CASE WHEN year < 50 THEN 1900 + year ELSE 2000 + year END;

// check
mysql> SELECT * FROM years;
+------+
| year |
+------+
| 2050 |
| 2090 |
| 1940 |
| 2085 |
+------+
```