# Phpmyadmin export a table from the database with dotted (formatted) output...

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I wish to export a table using phpMyAdmin, with formatted output. 
For instance, consider Alex's answer at this question :

[Edit mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256418/edit-mysql-table)

In his answer, he displays a table of values with dotted lines around it. That is the kind of formatted output I want to accomplish. I have seen similar outputs from others posts on this community.

How can I export or get a similar output of a table from `Phpmyadmin`?

Comment: provide some sample data from your tables and your desired output to better understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly export to Markdown from phpMyAdmin. Possibly the closest export type is Mediawiki table, so you might be able to manipulate that in to something you can use to post here.

Personally, most often, I write it out by hand and massage it with the tool at http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html which I found through the question at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post which I originally found by a Google search for "markdown database structure." I generally find that if a database structure is so long that I don't want to type by hand and instead find copy/paste necessary, that I probably haven't reduced the question or answer to enough of a [minimum test case.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)